# DataSpell (JetBrains) shows in Jupyter notebook the error: "WebGL is not supported by your browser ..."

Tags: python, jupyter, jetbrains-ide, dataspell

The following code works with Anaconda/Jupyter in the browser but not in the [DataSpell](https://www.jetbrains.com/de-de/dataspell/) Jupyter notebook. As output DataSpell shows: "WebGL is not supported by your browser …".

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

# Read data from a csv
z_data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=z_data.values)])

fig.update_layout(title='Mt Bruno Elevation', autosize=False,
                  width=500, height=500,
                  margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))

fig.show()
```

Comment: Is there any solution to this? Experiencing this on the latest version of DataSpell (2023.1) on Windows 10.